# Cloned item clone button will cause multiple items to be cloned

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jsp

I am trying to use Jquery to clone multiple form elements. The first clone button will work and successfully cloned the elements ONCE. However, the clone button in the cloned element will clone the elements more than once in 1 single click. I need these buttons to work the same and only clone the elements once. My code is below. Please help. Thanks in advance!

```js
var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
var cloneIndex = $(".searchForm").length;

function clone() {
    $(this).parents(".searchForm").clone()
        .appendTo(".search")
        .attr("id", "searchForm" + cloneIndex)
        .find("*")
        .each(function() {
            var id = this.id || "";
            var match = id.match(regex) || [];
            if (match.length == 3) {
                this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
            }
        })
        .on('click', 'button.add-more', clone)
        .on('click', 'button.remove', remove);
    cloneIndex++;
}

function remove() {
    $(this).parents(".searchForm").remove();
}
$("button.add-more").on("click", clone);

$("button.remove").on("click", remove);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<form method="post" action="searchServlet">
   <div class="search">
      <table id="searchForm1" class="searchForm">
         <tr>
            <td>SELECT TABLE*:</td>
            <td>
               <div class="searchDropdown">
                  <select name="table[]" class="table" id="table" onchange="change(this);">
                     <option>---Select Table---</option>
                     <option value="something">Something</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>SELECT COLUMN*:</td>
            <td>
               <div class="searchDropdown">
                  <select name="column[]" id="column">
                     <option>---Select Table First---</option>
                  </select>
               </div>
            </td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>CONDITION:</td>
            <td><input type="text" name="condition[]" id="condition" placeholder="Condition" /></td>
         </tr>
         <tr>
            <td>
               <button class="searchFormBtn add-more" type="button">Add</button>
               <button class="searchFormBtn remove" type="button">Remove</button>
            </td>
         </tr>
      </table>
   </div>
   <p id="importantNote">*Compulsory fields.</p>
   <p>
      <input id="submitQuery" type="submit" value="Query" />
   </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's because you're trying to clone the form part with buttons, which have already bound.

Just move event binding outside the clone function.

```js
var regex = /^(.+?)(\d+)$/i;
var cloneIndex = $(".searchForm").length;

$('.search').on('click', 'button.add-more', clone);
$('.search').on('click', 'button.remove', remove);

function clone() {
  $(this).parents(".searchForm").clone()
    .appendTo(".search")
    .attr("id", "searchForm" + cloneIndex)
    .find("*")
    .each(function() {
      var id = this.id || "";
      var match = id.match(regex) || [];
      if (match.length == 3) {
        this.id = match[1] + (cloneIndex);
      }
    })
  cloneIndex++;
}

function remove() {
  $(this).parents(".searchForm").remove();
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<form method="post" action="searchServlet">
  <div class="search">
    <table id="searchForm1" class="searchForm">
      <tr>
        <td>SELECT TABLE*:</td>
        <td>
          <div class="searchDropdown">
            <select name="table[]" class="table" id="table" onchange="change(this);">
                            <option>---Select Table---</option>
                            <option value="something">Something</option>
                        </select>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>SELECT COLUMN*:</td>
        <td>
          <div class="searchDropdown">
            <select name="column[]" id="column">
                            <option>---Select Table First---</option>
                        </select>
          </div>
        </td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>CONDITION:</td>
        <td><input type="text" name="condition[]" id="condition" placeholder="Condition" /></td>
      </tr>
      <tr>
        <td>
          <button class="searchFormBtn add-more" type="button">Add</button>
          <button class="searchFormBtn remove" type="button">Remove</button></td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </div>
  <p id="importantNote">*Compulsory fields.</p>
  <p>
    <input id="submitQuery" type="submit" value="Query" />
  </p>
</form>
```